# What is Kadison's process about cocycles?

Tags: homological-algebra, operator-algebras, homology-cohomology, von-neumann-algebras

My teacher told me the Kadison's process(may be not this ward, it is just my translation

) can make a 2-cocycle turn to be a cocycle(i.e.,derivation). But I can not find it in the internet. Thanks a lot to the one who tell me the Kadison's process.

Comment: As far as I know, I never heard about this, I suspect your teacher are talking about "Hochschild Cohomology of Von Neumann Algebras", a nice book on this topic is: http://books.google.com/books/about/Hochschild_Cohomology_of_Von_Neumann_Alg.html?id=-O-NJe3uJcUC

Comment: It is a nice book. Thank you!